# How to inherit an attribute in OCaml?

Tags: inheritance, ocaml

The Real World OCaml book, in its [Chapter 12](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/classes.html), shows how to inherit from a superclass' method, e.g. the method `push` below:

```
class double_stack init = object
  inherit [int] stack init as super

  method push hd =
    super#push (hd * 2)
end ;;
```

But then it mentions that `super` does not work as in Java:

> The preceding `as super` statement creates a special object called `super`
>   which can be used to call superclass methods. Note that `super` is not a
>   real object and can only be used to call methods.

Then how do I inherit from a superclass' attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may access attributes of inherited classes as if they were defined in the current class, pretty much like in many other object oriented languages; the access rule corresponds to `protected` level in C++: you cannot access an attribute from outside a class directly, excepted from an inheriting class.

The special provision given in the book is to explain that a method of a class cannot return `super`, because this symbol is just a syntactic device to access inherited methods. This device may be useful when these methods are being overridden by the current class or by another inherited class.

```
class foo = object
  val mutable v = "hello"
  method m = v
end
```

Accessing an inherited attribute:

```
class bar = object
  val w = "world"
  method! m = v ^ " " ^ w 
end
```

Note that the above `bar` class overrides the method `m`, which means that accessing the method of `foo` from within `bar` (in this example, of course, this is not necessary)  would require to qualify it as `super#m`.

Illegal use of a superclass name:

```
class wrong = object(self)
  inherit foo as super
  method w = super (* cannot compile *)
end

Error: Ancestor names can only be used to select inherited methods
```

The proper way to implement such semantic is to return `self` *casted* as its superclass:

```
class correct = object(self)
  inherit foo as super
  method w = (self :> foo)  
end
```